# How to handle 2 controller and models with nearly the same data in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am starting with MVC since a few weeks and now I have a best practice question:

I have basic data of my project, which are around 30 to 40 propertys, mostly strings.
I have a model with all my propertys for this data called "GeneralDataModel" and of course a Controller "GeneralDataController" and my View "GeneralDataView".

Now I want to have a setting page for this data.
I created a view (GeneralDataSettingView) a controller (GeneralDataSettingController) and a Model (GeneralDataSettingModel).

In fact, most of the data are the same, e.g. I have to load all data into the model when the view is loaded to display them in my TextboxFor.
Some methods are not the same, e.g. a method to save my data which only my setting page but not the display page have.

I know a few methods to have not the same model data and controller methods over and over again - e.g. I could work with inheritance, I could simply extract the methods in a class above where both controllers have access too...

What is the best practice here?

Comment: What would (GeneralDataView) view display?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the "pull data for all views in group" approach, especially if you have to hit multiple tables and pull data you are not using in a particular set of data in a specific view.

One pattern that can work, depending on your need, is pull the common data and then use a decorator pattern to pull the additional data. But jumping to decorator can be dangerous, as it leads you to try to use it everywhere.

I like the "solve for each page and then refactor to patterns" approach, as you are not trying to then make things fit to the first pattern you find (ie, the hammer searching for nails methodology). But, if you have the pattern that shows a pattern like decorator solves the problem efficiently, then go that direction.

Hope this helps.